# UICollection View causes "UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes" on smaller devices

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

On an iPhone 6 Plus, the collection view cells are fine, but when testing on another device size like the iPhone 5, i'm bombarded with "

> 017-06-15 01:59:25.744 HyperTest[3865:8825385] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   2017-06-15 01:59:25.744 HyperTest[3865:8825385] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
>   2017-06-15 01:59:25.745 HyperTest[3865:8825385] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 219}> collection view layout: .
>   2017-06-15 01:59:25.745 HyperTest[3865:8825385] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.

especially when I do this:

```
let layout = billFeedCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout // casting is required because UICollectionViewLayout doesn't offer header pin. It's feature of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    layout?.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
```

anyway, I can resolve this problem? I need to ensure that the cell scales and fits all devices.

Comment: You should adopt `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol for customizing your layouts.

Comment: Jevon please have a look at the answer, also let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By confirming `UICollectionViewDelegate` from your class. The delegate method `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` will call from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and this will call in your class now you can return the size of `UICollectionViewCell`.

*This works for me*

**method:**

```
collectionView.delegate = self

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Comment: This would only work in cases in which the cells themselves are equal to the size and width of the device, not in cases where the cell are trying to be proportional to the screen size.

Comment: That is your calculation you can give your size that is only for example.

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible that when you have a collectionView in a UITableViewCell this cell actually resizes the collectionView height to 0.

In my case, the `collectionView` is showing an array of `UIImageView` to display some image gallery in each cell.
If the cell is not supposed to show any images (text without image for example), the `collectionView` is hidden.

The `collectionView`, if put within a StackView might need to have a height constraint and to avoid conflicts, you might need to set it to priority 999.

Then, when you **hide** the `collectionView`, it will actually try to set the height to 0.
The collectionView can still contain images in it and that will trigger the error.

**SOLUTION**: empty your `datasource` and reload the `collectionView` when you configure your cell.

Comment: this is the only real answer.

Comment: It's not complete as the real solution is to set image constraints width and height, however, your analysis of the problem is good and it deserved my upvote.

Comment: You got the problem, but my collectionView keeps getting 0 height on log even though its actually not. The app works as expected, but I just want to remove the warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let cellsize = CGSize(width: (CollectionView.bounds.size.width/2) - 12, height:(CollectionView.bounds.size.height/3) - 20)



        return cellsize
    }
```

**here CollectionView is outlet of UICollectionView**