# Swift 3 iOS 10 - UICollectionView with image and text doesn't show up properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm a beginner iOS developer and i got stuck on implementing an UICollectionView. Here how it's showing :

[image]

Here's how i designed it in Storyboard :

[image]

I'm trying to implement this based on this tutorial :

[UICollectionView with Swift: Build Carousel Like Home Screen - iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG7mWFcU0vk&t=2s)

Here is my ViewController class :

```
class SelectMorphologyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

      var morphology = Morphology.getMorphology()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

     struct Storyboard {
        static let cellIdentifier = "Morphology cell"
    }

}

extension SelectMorphologyViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return morphology.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MorphologyCollectionViewCell


        cell.morphology = self.morphology[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
}
```

The model class :

```
class Morphology
{
    var title = ""
    var image : UIImage!

    init(title : String , image : UIImage) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
    }


    static func getMorphology() -> [Morphology] {


        return [Morphology(title : "Les épaules qui s’alignent avec les hanches." , image : UIImage (named: "8")!), Morphology(title : "Les épaules et des hanches dans le même alignement et une taille très peu marquée. " , image : UIImage (named: "h")!),Morphology(title : "Une petite poitrine, une taille fine et des épaules sont dans l’alignement des hanches." , image : UIImage (named: "x")!),Morphology(title : "Une carrure est plus large que les hanches." , image : UIImage (named: "v")!),Morphology(title : "Une carrure plus étroite que les hanches. " , image : UIImage (named: "a")!),Morphology(title : "La femme ronde :) " , image : UIImage (named: "o")!)]

    }

}
```

And finally my CollectionViewCell class :

```
class MorphologyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


var morphology : Morphology! {

    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!




private func updateUI() {
    image?.image! = morphology.image
    title?.text! = morphology.title

   }

}
```

Here's some images for my Storyboard settings :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: add Some code what you are doing ,

Comment: Can you please add your code for the collectionView delegate and data source, and your storyboard settings related to your collection view layout?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559745/uicollection-view-causes-uicollectionviewflowlayoutbreakforinvalidsizes-on-sma/44560534#44560534

Comment: Have you added Layout constraints on you CollectionView

Answer (score 0):

You should try **sizeForItemAt indexPath** something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    }
```

Comment: I just added this function and nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

> **My answer would be more accurate If you had posted some code**

It seems the problem is with **UICollectionViewCell** sizing. Storyboard won't reflect how the cells will be presented, it's more a visual thing to you. In order to fix it, you might need to implement:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Add this function and change as per you needs**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - 5), height: CGFloat(135)) // 2 is for number of cell in one row you can change as per your needs
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }

    func  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                         layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                         minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }
```